# Adding a missing GAP package to Sage

Tags: sage

A function I want to use in Sage throws an exception because it is missing GAP's package "[HAP](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/hap.html)". I can download this package, but I don't know how to make Sage recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer myself, the relevant page is [this](http://www.sagemath.org/packages/optional/).

> To install one of these packages, type e.g., the following at the UNIX shell prompt:

```
    sage -i db-jones-2005-11-02
```

> Note that the package name contains the version number, and it will be
>   downloaded automatically if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can type in

```
sage -optional
```

to get a list of optional sage packages. install them like

```
sage -i database_gap
```

PS: if your download is slow, go into the packages directory on a sage mirror. then copy/paste the full URL.